# VHDL cant determine definition of operator ''='' -- found 0 definitions

Tags: vhdl

```
case state is  
    when (state = 0) =>     
        win <= 0;
        stand <= 0;
        bust <= 0;
        hit <=0;
        state <= "1";
```

my `when (state = 0) =>` has the error. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but have you tried to look into a VHDL book or some online tutorials? This code is far away from any switch, case or select statement of any programming language.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems here:
1. Your case statement is syntactically incorrect. Use `when 0 =>` instead of `when (state = 0) =>`.
2. Can you show us how the declaration of `state` looks like? It looks like either you have declared `state` as a `std_logic_vector` but compare it to an integer `0` or you have declared `state` as an integer and assign a `std_logic_vector` to it.

Answer (score 0):

A basic template for state machines (2 process style).

Architeture:

```
type T_STATE is (ST_IDLE, ST_WORKING);

signal State      : T_STATE   := ST_IDLE;
signal NextState  : T_STATE;
```

Body:

```
process(Clock)
begin
  if rising_edge(Clock) then
    if (Reset = '1') then
      State <= ST_IDLE;
    else
      State <= NextState;
    end if;
  end if;
end process;

process(State, Input)
begin
  NextState    <= State;

  -- default assignments
  Output       <= '0';

  case State is
    when ST_IDLE =>
      if (Input = '1') then
        NextState  <= ST_WORKING;
      end if;

    when ST_WORKING =>
      Output       <= '1';
      NextState    <= ST_IDLE;

  end case;
end process;
```